# why do I have to reshape `inputs` from `tf.train.batch()` to use with `slim.fully_connected()?

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

Why do I get this error for `slim.fully_connected()`?

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer fc1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [32]`

my input is `Tensor("batch:0", shape=(32,), dtype=float32)` from `tf.train.batch()`

```
  inputs, labels = tf.train.batch(
        [input, label],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_threads=1,
        capacity=2 * batch_size)
```

if I reshape the input to `(32,1)` it works fine.

```
inputs, targets = load_batch(train_dataset)
print("inputs:", inputs, "targets:", targets)
# inputs: Tensor("batch:0", shape=(32,), dtype=float32) targets: Tensor("batch:1", shape=(32,), dtype=float32)

inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1,1])
targets = tf.reshape(targets, [-1,1])
```

The examples in [slim walkthrough](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/slim_walkthrough.ipynb) seem to work without explicitly reshaping after `load_batch()`

Answer (score 0):

`tf.train.batch` expects array like inputs because scalars are quite rare (practically speaking). So, you have to reshape your input. I think the next code snippet would clear things out.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> a.shape
(4,)
>>> a = np.reshape(a,[4,1])
>>> a
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
>>>
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but my np.array looks like this `shape x= (5, 1) [[4.6446195]
 [9.981602 ]
 [7.1564007]
 [8.539308 ]
 [2.0904353]]` and I'm using `tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value= inputs[m].tolist() ))` so I can't believe it comes out as an array of scalars and not an array of arrays.

Comment: I have never used `tf.train.FloatList` before but apparently it is running a `tf.squeeze` before saving the data. The API docs is empty, will have to verify by looking at the code.